# How can I use an environment variable in a Postgres function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, environment-variables

Let's say I have a windows user environment variable SOME_STRING.

Is it possible to use its value in a PL/pgSQL function?

If not, do I need to use an untrusted language (like PL/pythonu) or can I use a trusted one?

I am on PG 9.2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can not access a environment variable directly; but you can access a custom configuration setting and set that to a value from the environment at startup.  For example, you can pass the follow startup option using `PGOPTIONS`:

```
PGOPTIONS="-c 'custom.some_string=${SOME_STRING}'"
```

Note: the dot (`.`) in the name is important.

Then retrieve the value using `current_setting`:

```
SELECT current_setting('custom.some_string');
```

(I have tried this on Linux and found it to be working, it should be the same for Windows, but may need some slight modification to cater for that particular platform.)

Custom parameters have been possible since postgresql version 8.0 with the use of `custom_variable_classes` (see [16.4.12. Customized Options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/runtime-config.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CUSTOM))  Since postgresql version 10.0, the use of `custom_variable_classes` is not necessary but the parameter name must still consist of two parts, separated by a `.`, first a variable class name, then the variable name.  The class name should be unique across all loaded modules.

Comment: What postgresql version?

Comment: @dmvianna, I've updated the answer with details for specific versions. TL;DR v8.0 or greater.

Comment: I couldn’t do this in 14, but instead I was able to assign variables using `psql -v variable_name=“$ENV_VARIABLE”` and then using it within scripts as `:variable_name`.

Comment: @dmvianna, that's fair, OP was asking about the use in PL/pgSQL function, which means the value would need to be set when the _server_ starts.  You appear to be using an envvar from the client's environment (i.e. `psql`), which is a little different. Having said this, I thought that the method I described should still be applicable 

Answer (score 1):

**To set a env variable in session level:**

```
set db.beta = 'Stored in env variable';
```

(db.beta can be replaced with any string as desired but it should have dot(.) in-between)

**To use env variable in your query:**

```
create table neo(display text);

insert into neo values((SELECT current_setting('db.beta')));
```

**To set env variable globally**, put the variable in `postgresql.conf` file under `CUSTOMIZED OPTIONS` like below.

```
db.beta = 'Stored in env variable'
```

Comment: this is very helpful!